# size of createElement("svg") is 0,0

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to create an SVG with JS and set the size, but when I use `createElement("svg")`, the generated HTML is

```
<svg class="jscreated" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></svg>
```

but the svg size is shown as `0,0`.

See this example:

```js
var svg=document.createElement("svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);
svg.setAttribute("class","jscreated");
svg.style.width="500px";
svg.style.height="400px";
```

```html
<svg class="HTML_SVG" style="width:500px; height:400px;" class="HTML_SVG"></svg>
```

You can see that the SVG created by JS is `0,0` but the direct in HTML written one is 500x400 as it should be. What does the `"==$0"` in the Chrome inspector mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

createElement can only create HTML elements, you need createElementNS

```js
var svg=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);
svg.setAttribute("class","jscreated");
svg.style.width="500px";
svg.style.height="400px";
```

```html
<svg class="HTML_SVG" style="width:500px; height:400px;" class="HTML_SVG"></svg>
```